# C++ Printing a queue in reverse without using a stack or doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

A part of my assignment is for output of our code to be printed in the reverse order of the linked list queue.  I spoke to my instructor, and he said he does not want it done with a stack.  Without the option of transitioning the queue into a stack and he also does not want is to make it a doubly linked list, i have no idea how to print this.  Does anyone know a way that i am missing?  Ive included everything I've written.  Any ideas will be considered and thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class queue{
 public:
 queue();
 void enq(int);
 void deq();
 int front();
 bool isEmpty();
 void printq();  //print que in reverse
private:
 struct node{
     int val;
     node* next;
  };
node* topPtr;
};

queue::queue()
{
topPtr = NULL;
}

void queue::enq(int x)
{
if (topPtr == NULL)
{
    topPtr = new node;
    topPtr->val = x;
    topPtr->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    node* tmp;
    tmp = topPtr;
    while (tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = new node;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->val = x;
  }
}

void queue::deq()
{
node* rem = topPtr;
topPtr = topPtr->next;
delete(rem);
}

int queue::front()
{
return topPtr->val;
}

bool queue::isEmpty()
{
if (topPtr == NULL)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

void queue::printq()
{
      ////totally lost here
}

int main()
 {
  ifstream cmds("cmd.txt");
  int cmd, op;
  queue s;
  bool isEmpty;

while (cmds >> cmd)
{
    switch (cmd)
    {
    case 1:
        cmds >> op;
        s.enq(op);
        break;
    case 2:
        s.deq();
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Top: " << s.front() << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        empty = s.isEmpty();
        if (empty)
            cout << "queue is empty" << endl;
        else
            cout << "queue is not empty" << endl;
        break;
    case 5:     //print case

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each time you're going to add a new item, check the current queue size. Add the new item, then remove all the previously existing items, and immediately add each of them back into the queue. Once you've added all the items, remove and print them normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate from the back index / pointer to the front index / pointer, depending on how you insert (could be swapped).

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function.

This way, you didn't use a stack explicitly. however you are using the call stack implicitly.

PS: I didn't write any code or mention exactly what to do, but gave a hint. since it's an assignment and you should do it yourself.